# get text from pdf - groovy

Tags: java, pdf, groovy, pdfbox

I need to extract text from a pdf using Groovy.

This is my code:

```
def PDDocumentClass =  Class.forName("org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument", true, urlLoader);
def PDPageClass =  Class.forName("org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage", true, urlLoader);
def PDFTextStripper =  Class.forName("org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper", true, urlLoader);
def pdfTextStripperArea =  Class.forName("org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripperByArea", true, urlLoader);
def pdfTextRandom =  Class.forName("org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessFile", true, urlLoader);

def d = docman.getNodeByName(docman.getNode(346462 as long), "cv1.pdf").content

File f1 = new File("${d.content}")

def pdfstrip = PDFTextStripper.getText(PDDocumentClass.load(f1))
```

but the execution of this code gives me the following error:

```
No signature of method: static org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.getText() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument) values: [org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument@1590d92b]
Possible solutions: getText(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument), endText(), beginText(), getAt(java.lang.String), getLevel(), writeText(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument, java.io.Writer)
```

I'm sure the argument passed to the getText() method is a PDDocument, the required type!

When I try to create a new instace of PdfTextStripper I receive this error:
[error instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zoCX.png)

Comment: I don't know anything about groovy but to me it looks as if you're using PDFTextStripper.getText() as a static call but it isn't. You need to create a stripper object first.

Comment: Why are you loading all the classes with Class.forName?

Comment: In addition to what @TilmanHausherr and @tim_yates have written, since Groovy allows you to write Java statements, just follow an example of extracting text using PDFBox that is written in Java. It should be quite straight forward. Here's an example: `https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pdfbox/pdfbox_reading_text.htm`

Comment: @TilmanHausherr because when I try to create a new stripped object I receive an error on console. The same happens when I try adding the library using standard import instruction.

Comment: @tim_yates I'm working with groovy using answer module integrated in OpenText platform and I believe that it's the only way to import external class

Comment: Create a new PDFTextStripper() instance before calling getText, e.g. `new PDFTextStripper().getText(...)`

Comment: @aspok thanks but I receive an error on console when create a new instance of the class using 'new'

Comment: @ilary then please include that error message in your question in full (you can edit)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I add an image with the error in my question

Comment: thanks to everyone but I solved!

Comment: So what was the problem? You can answer the question yourself if you want.